# How can I use draw.io hyperlink to address local files

Tags: links, app.diagrams.net

How can we set hyperlinks to our local files in draw.io?

- The hyperlink `http://www.google.com` works.
- The hyperlink `c:\readMe.txt` does not.

I am using draw.io from Chrome app center on my laptop. And the files are saved locally.

Answer (score 1):

You can't:

1. The browser permission (even in Chrome app mode) doesn't allow this.
2. We have to sanitize data associated with shapes to avoid XSS attacks, the local file system reference would be affected by this.